# Where do return values will be stored with this line of code: " const { value: { name, email, password } } = await ctx.request.body().value; "

Tags: typescript, syntax, deno

I can not understand where do variables those come from `ctx.request.body().value`, will be stored?

```
const { value: { name, email, password } } = await ctx.request.body().value;
```

Why we don't just use the following line instead of the above one?

```
const { name, email, password }  = await ctx.request.body().value;
```

Or why we don't use `const value = await ctx.request.body().value;` and then use `value.name` , `value.email` , `value.password`?

May someone explains a little about this syntax?

Comment: This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DemiPixel suggested in the comment, a look into object deconstruction might help make it clear, basically the difference between the statements you wrote is the expected value of `ctx.request.body()`.

In the first case, you assume that the body looks a bit like this:
`{value: {value: {name: '', email: '', password: ''}}`, as you expect to deconstruct an object with key `value`, but you already get the `.value` from your response. This might be the reason it might not work as you expected.

The second case assumes the body looks like this: `{value: {name: '', email: '', password: ''}`, thus if you deconstruct ctx.request.body().value you indeed get `const { name, email, password }`.

Hope it makes it a bit more clear